# Two separate behaviors for back button pressed

Tags: java, android

Rather new to Android development and I'm having a difficult time trying to solve this odd behavior.

The back button in the upper left corner of my application acts differently then the back button built into the phone. The back button in the app will load a new activity of its parent rather then using `finish()` to return to its parent.

The devices built in back button works as intended. I have put break points on `onBackPressed()` and it's called without issue.

Do I have to provide an `OnClickListener` for the app back button? I figured something like this would of already been taken care of by the SDK. Ideas?

Comment: let me know if my answer works for you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, you need to get the reference of your `toolbar`, then you have to set the listener:

```
toolbar.setNavigationOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                //you can call onBackPressed here
                onBackPressed();
            }
        });
```

Comment: Worked perfectly. Thank you!